# Xcode 6..0.1 fails to compile storyboard

Tags: xcode6, ibtool

I just upgraded my Xcode to 6.0.1 and I am not able to compile anymore. Xcode build is failing with following error:

```
    nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
2014-09-18 12:46:28.977 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[19152:359412] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2cb5b5800 UIImageView:0x7fb2cb5893e0.centerY == UITableViewLabel:0x7fb2cb5a8950.centerY>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2014-09-18 12:46:28.978 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[19152:359412] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCellContentView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:558
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this note in the log:

When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.

Add a symbolic breakpoint:
-[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:]

Also you might just want to clear the constraints for the view involved.